# Cannot create a controller in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm a beginning Magento programmer. I used to access the backend as localhost/magento/admin and everything was working fine on WAMP. I could access any route I set up in config.xml as localhost/magento/(frontName) and my controllers were working fine.

Then I was trying to get Zend Debugger working with Eclipse, and in the process I fiddled with things, reinstalled WAMP and Magento a couple of times, installed Zend Server CE and later removed it, and MAYBE fiddled with some settings - don't remember exactly what I changed.

Ultimately, I'm back on WAMP, but now localhost/magento/admin is broken and the backend must be accessed as localhost/magento/index.php/admin, which is ugly. Also, I can't get any routes working. localhost/magento/(frontName) is broken, localhost/magento/index.php/(frontName) gives a 404 error within Magento.

I've been trying to fix this for nearly 2 days now; I'd be grateful for any help. Sorry about the n00b question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you are sure the mod rewrite is enabled? Can you get to the frontend at all? do you have sample data installed can you get to any products or categories?

Comment: Thanks for the reply; mod_rewrite was disabled! I enabled it, and now I can access the backend at localhost/magento/admin, as before. However, I still cannot access my custom route (404 error). The frontend opens fine at localhost/magento. I don't have the sample data installed.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
 <modules>
  <Atriya_Test>
   <version>0.1.0</version>
  </Atriya_Test>
 </modules>
 
 <frontend>
  <routers>
   <test>
    <use>standard</use>
    <args>
     <Module>Atriya_Test</Module>
     <frontName>test</frontName>
    </args>
   </test>
  </routers>
 </frontend>
</config>

Comment: So sorry about this... somehow the indentation gets removed when I click 'Add Comment'.

Comment: Gosh... just discovered that changing <Module> to <module> solves everything. :( Sorry for bothering everyone. I'm new to PHP, new to MVC, and the only programming I've done before is writing silly programs (find the first 20 prime numbers) in C, and now I'm suddenly neck-deep in Magento, and gasping for breath. :(

Comment: no problem, we have all been there and ask questions that end up being something stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

you probably didn't understand very well how works exactly the config.xml in your controller. look at http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-create-controller-36

good luck

Comment: Haha! Thanks for the reply, but since I asked this question, I've switched jobs, switched work areas, changed location, changed profession. I have no longer anything to do with Magento, PHP, online stores, or web development in general! :D